# Xarray: grouping by contiguous identical values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

In Pandas, it is simple to slice a series(/array) such as `[1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1]` to return groups of `[1,1,1,1]`, `[2,2,]`,`[1,1,1,1]`. To do this, I use the syntax:

```
 datagroups= df[key].groupby(df[key][df[key][variable] == some condition].index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum())
```

...where I would obtain individual groups by `df[key][variable] == some condition`. Groups that have the same value of some condition that aren't contiguous are their own groups. If the condition was `x < 2`, I would end up with `[1,1,1,1]`,`[1,1,1,1]` from the above example.

I am attempting to do the same thing in [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/getting-started-guide/installing.html) package, because I am working with multidimensional data, but the above syntax obviously doesn't work.

What I have been successful doing so far:

#### a) apply some condition to separate the values I want by NaNs:

```
 datagroups_notsplit = df[key].where(df[key][variable] == some condition)
```

So now I have groups as in the example above `[1,1,1,1,Nan,Nan,1,1,1,1]` (if some condition was `x <2`). The question is, how do I cut these groups so that it becomes `[1,1,1,1]`,`[1,1,1,1]`?

#### b) Alternatively, group by some condition...

```
 datagroups_agglomerated = df[key].groupby_bins('variable', bins = [cleverly designed for some condition])
```

But then, following the example above, I end up with groups `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, `[2,2]`. Is there a way to then groupby the groups on noncontiguous index values?

Comment: This question is not very focused unless you add the justification: given you know a lot of pandas functionality (e.g. `isna()`/`notna()`/`dropna()`) are missing from xarray, why must you use xarray? Recommend you raise an [enhance request for `isna/notna/dropna()` on xarray](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions?discussions_q=dropna).  And what is so invariant about 'some condition' that you can't just add a gating condition that the terms are not NA?

Comment: As to your motivating examples, is your domain always limited to small integers? or else what? (can you show a better example?) Then if xarray currently doesn't fully support NA, we can fall back on the old tricks with integer sentinels e.g. 9999, sys.maxint, (or Infinity for floats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about what your 'some condition' can be, or the domain of your data (small integers only?), I'd just workaround the missing pandas functionality, something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

dat = xr.DataArray([1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1], dims='x')

# Use `diff()` to get groups of contiguous values
(dat.diff('x') != 0)]

# ...prepend a leading 0 (pedantic syntax for xarray)
xr.concat([xr.DataArray(0), (dat.diff('x') != 0)], 'x')

# ...take cumsum() to get group indices
xr.concat([xr.DataArray(0), (dat.diff('x') != 0)], 'x').cumsum()
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])

dat.groupby(xr.concat([xr.DataArray(0), (dat.diff('x') != 0)], 'x').cumsum() )
# DataArrayGroupBy, grouped over 'group'
# 3 groups with labels 0, 1, 2.
```

The xarray [*How do I*](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/howdoi.html) page could use some recipes like this (*"Group contiguous values"*), suggest you contact them and have them added.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was a bit more complicated than the minimal example I posted due to the use of timeseries indices and the desire to subselect certain conditions; however, I was able to adapt the answer of smci, above in the following way:

(1) create indexnumber variable:

> df = Dataset( data_vars={
> 'some_data' : (('date'), some_data),
> 'more_data' : (('date'), more_data),
> 'indexnumber' : (('date'), arange(0,len(date_arr))
> },
> coords={
> 'date' : date_arr
> }
> )

(2) get the indices for the groupby groups:

> ind_slice = df.where(df['more_data'] == some_condition)['indexnumber'].dropna(dim='date').diff(dim='date') !=1).cumsum().indexes

(3) get the cumsum field:

> sumcum  = df.where(df['more_data'] == some_condition)['indexnumber'].dropna(dim='date').diff(dim='date') !=1).cumsum()

(4) reconstitute a new df:

> df2 = df.loc[ind_slice]

(5) add the cumsum field:

> df2['sumcum'] = sumcum

(6) groupby:

> groups = df2.groupby(df['sumcum'])

hope this helps anyone else out there looking to do this.